# What is the probability of rolling at least 3 2s OR at least 3 6s in 6 rolls?

Tags: probability, inclusion-exclusion

I now understand how I can calculate exactly 3 2s and 3 6s in 6 rolls, but how do I approach the 'At least' and 'or' conditions of this question?

Answer (score 1):

There are $5^{6-k}\binom6k$ ways to have exactly $k$ $2$s, and the same for $6$s, so that gives a total of

$$
2\sum_{k=3}^65^{6-k}\binom6k=2(125\cdot20+25\cdot15+5\cdot6+1)=5812\;.
$$

But now we've double-counted the $\binom63=20$ ways of having three $2$s and three $6$s, so the actual total is $5812-20=5792$.

This could be done *ad hoc* because there was only one way to fulfil both conditions; to more systematically solve more complicated problems of this sort, you can use  [inclusion-exclusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle).

Answer (score 1):

You generally need to add up all propabilities which ''at least'' or ''at most'' refer to.

Probability of getting exactly $k$ successes in $n$ trials is given by the formula:

$$
\frac{n!}{k!\cdot (n-k)!} p^k (1-p)^{n-k} \text{,}
$$
where $p$ stands for probability of success in each trial.

If you want to calculate the probability of getting at least $3$ twos in 6 rolls you need sum the above formula from $k=3$ to $k=6$, so effectively you'll get:

$$
\sum_{k=3}^6  \frac{6!}{k!\cdot (6-k)!} \left(\frac{1}{6}\right)^k \left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^{6-k} \text{.}
$$